# Why is merging of two network streams in ffmpeg raising RTP errors?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take the video stream from network stream A, while taking the audio stream from network stream B.

I tried the command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1 -i http://192.168.1.2 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -f mp4 out.mp4
```

Which continuously raises the following errors:

```
[rtsp @ 0x564b44779f60] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x564b44779f60] RTP: missed 591 packets
```

While the commands

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1 -c copy -f mp4 out.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i http://192.168.1.2 -c copy -f mp3 out.mp3
```

work without problems.

The video stream is HEVC, the audio stream is MP3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Looks like the packet loss increases when using two or more sources at once. If anyone knows why, an answer on this would still be appreciated.

However, the packet loss can obviously be prevented by using TCP as transport protocol for RTSP:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://...
```

and I get even better results by additionally raising the `thread_queue_size`:

```
-thread_queue_size 1024
```

Both mentioned options are input options and have to go before the `-i`.